Factorial in assembly, output not correct
section .text 
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 15
    mov ebx, 1
lb:
    imul eax, ebx
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx,15
    jl lb

    mov ebx, eax
    mov eax, 1
    int 80h

I am new to assembly, I have this code to calculate factorial of 15, I know exit code in ebx should be between 0 and 255 but I will run this in gdb, but this isn't working properly help and also how should i output this value in kernel, give a simple explanation I'm new

That's a confusing way to do a factorial but it should work. At least as far as the low 32 bits are considered since 15 factorial does not fit into 32 bits. 15! = 1307674368000 = 0x13077775800 and your code correctly produces eax = 0x77775800

Thx how should I output in kernel, and what do you mean confusing, is there a better way?

You are doing 15*1*2*3*...*12*13*14 and you have the constant 15 twice in the code so if you ever want to change the value you have to do it in two places. As for printing, you will need to convert to text and print that. See for example this answer As I said, your code only produces the low 32 bits so depending on your requirements either rewrite the code for 64 bit numbers or try with a smaller number (12 is the most that fits).

oh thx, yea i will change to 64 bits but what if we wanna use numbers larger than 64 bits? Just out of curiosity

You can write code to use as many bits as you need.
